# What exactly is a "Chaattan"?

Tags: mantras, tantra, siddhi, sadhana, devatas

In Kerala,there is a continued tradition of worshipping "Chaatan".They are believed to be beings who can harm ,and are sent by an individual for a specific purpose(possibly even death).They have been known to disrespectfully treat murthis of devtas,as part of their acts; most famous among them being the Avanangattu Chaatans.

Can someone elucidate on these beings and their status?Thanks!